# Navigation buttons horizontal looping function

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops, navigation

I have a section element that is 5 times the width of the window width. It is sliding to the left by 1 window width by a looping function. This is working very good, but I want two arrow buttons so the user can interact and decide what he wants to see. How do I create these buttons with jQuery?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="left"></a>
<a href="#" id="right"></a>
<section>
    <article id="a1">
        ...
    </article>

    <article id="a2">
        ...
    </article>

    <article id="a3">
        ...
    </article>
</section>
```

The jQuery function for the looping animation is this:

```
var breedte = $(window).width();
function animateSection() {

    $('section').delay(5000).animate({ marginLeft: (-breedte) }, 1000)          
    .delay(5000).animate({ marginLeft: -(breedte*2) }, 1000)                
    .delay(5000).animate({ marginLeft: -(breedte*3) }, 1000)
    .delay(5000).animate({ marginLeft: -(breedte*4) }, 1000)        
    .delay(5000).animate({ marginLeft: -(breedte*5) }, 1000)            
    .delay(500).animate({ marginLeft: 0}, 10);

    animateSection();
}

animateSection();
```

How can I make these buttons so that when I click the "left" button, the section element will animate back to the previous article?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off adding a new class `active` to the active `article`.

```
var breedte = $(window).width();
function animateSection() {
    var current = $('article.active').removeClass('active');
    var prev = current.prev();
    var next = current.next().addClass('active');
    $(current).animate({ marginLeft: (-$(window).width()) }, 1000);
    $(next).css({ marginLeft: ($(window).width()) }).animate({marginLeft: 0 }, 1000);
}
$('article').first().addClass('active');
setInterval(animateSection,5000);
```

Your 'prev' and 'next' buttons will call `animateSection` to animate the next article accordingly. I hope this is a good starting point.